# Cloning mechanize.Browser yields to an error

Tags: python, python-2.7, mechanize-python

I am currently trying to send multiple requests with the mechanize.Browser object at once and my approach was to start some threads.
Each thread should clone the mechanize.Browser object and send the requests.
But copying the object causes a TypeError:

```
    TypeError: object.__new__(cStringIO.StringO) is not safe, use cStringIO.StringO.__new__()
```

But I can't figure out how to get it running.
After opening some pages I spawn the threads and do:

```
    newbr = copy.deepcopy(br)
```

which causes the error.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Why are you making copies of the `Browser` instance?

Comment: Because I want to follow a link with multiple threads.
Following a link changes the object state, so the other threads can not do the same

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, as addressed on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800393/recovering-from-httperror-in-mechanize) SO post.

One solution is to follow the link, then use the `br.back()` function to get back to the initial state later.

If this doesn't work (it didn't for me), if you're not against using other libraries, you can use the very good `requests` library to follow the link instead. In my case, I wanted to fill in a form and submit it with either `post` or `get`, which I was able to do using the following code (it should only need minor modification to follow links instead, using a `for links in br.links()` loop, for example)

```
import mechanize
import requests

def testErrorCodes(br,theCodes):
    for x in theCodes:

        br.select_form(nr=0)

        theAction = br.action
        payload = {'code': x}

        response = requests.post(theAction, data=payload)
        print response.status_code

br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open("http://savanttools.com/test-http-status-codes")

testErrorCodes(br,[401,402,403,404,500,503,504]) # Prints the error codes 

testErrorCodes(br,[404]) # The browser is still alive and well to be used again!
```