# Recovering from HTTPError in Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, http-error

I am writing a function for some existing python code that will be passed a Mechanize browser object as a parameter.

I fill in some details in a form in the browser, and use `response = browser.submit()` to move the browser to a new page, and collect some information from it.

Unfortunately, I occasionally get the following error:

`httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error`

I've navigated to the page in my own browser, and sure enough, I occasionally see this error directly, so I think this is a server problem, not anything to do with `robots.txt`, headers or similar.

The problem is that after submitting, the state of the `browser` object changes and I can't continue to use it. My first thought was to try taking a deep copy first and use that if I ran into problems, but that gives the error `TypeError: object.__new__(cStringIO.StringO) is not safe, use cStringIO.StringO.__new__()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835859/cloning-mechanize-browser-yields-to-an-error).

I've also tried using `browser.back()` but get `NoneType` errors.

Does anyone have a good solution to this?

## Solution (with thanks to karnesJ.R below):

A great solution below uses the excellent `requests` library (docs [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)). `requests` has functionality to fill in a form and submit via `post` or `get`, which importantly doesn't change the state of the `br` object.

An [excellent website](http://savanttools.com/test-http-status-codes) allows us to test various error codes, and has a form interface at the top that I've tested this on. I create a `br` object at this site, then define a function that selects the form from `br`, pulls out the relevant information, but does the submit via `requests` - so that the `br` object hasn't changed and is re-usable. Error codes cause `requests` to return rubbish, but don't render the `br` unusable.

As stated below, this involves a little more setup time, but is well worth it.

```
import mechanize
import requests

def testErrorCodes(br,theCodes):
    for x in theCodes:
        
        br.select_form(nr=0)
        
        theAction = br.action
        payload = {'code': x}

        response = requests.post(theAction, data=payload)
        print response.status_code

br=mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open("http://savanttools.com/test-http-status-codes")

testErrorCodes(br,[401,402,403,404,500,503,504]) # Prints the error codes 

testErrorCodes(br,[404]) # The browser is still alive and well to be used again!
```

Comment: Can you update us with the code that you have used till now?

Comment: You could try using selenuim.

Comment: Can you show your code or provide the site URL you're trying to access?

Comment: Some cartoon code added above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a while since I've written for python, but I think I have a workaround for your problem. Try this method:

```
import requests
except Mechanize.HTTPError:
    while true: ## DANGER ##
        ## You will need to format and/or decode the POST for your form
        response = requests.post('http://yourwebsite.com/formlink', data=None, json=None)
        ## If the server will accept JSON formatting, this becomes trivial
        if response.status_code == accepted_code: break
```

You can find documentation about the `requests` library [here](https://realpython.com/python-requests/). I personally think that `requests` is better for your case than `mechanize`... but it does require a little more overhead from you in that you need to break down the submission to raw POST using some kind of RESTful interceptor in your browser.

Ultimately though, by passing in `br` you are restricting yourself to the way that mechanize handles browser states on `br.submit()`.

Comment: This works - I've edited my question above to incorporate your insight. `requests` is certainly a much nicer interface than `mechanize`. Bounty well earned!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want the submission to happen even if it takes multiple tries.

The solution that I thought of is certainly not efficient, but it should work.

```
def do_something_in_mechanize():
    <...insert your code here...>
    try:
        browser.submit()
        <...rest of your code...>
    except mechanize.HTTPError:
        do_something_in_mechanize()
```

Basically, it'll call the function until the action is performed without `HTTPError`s.

Comment: The problem is that the browser is passed in as a parameter - I need to repeat the `browser.submit()` step within the `except` block, but by that stage the browser has already changed state and re-calling the `browser.submit()` causes `NoneType` errors - if you put `browser` into `do_something_in_mechanize()` it won't work after an `HTTPError`

Comment: the do_something_in_mechanize() function should contain the entire code from the instantiation of browser to the end. If that is feasible, this solution would work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly the problem - the `browser` is being passed to my code as a parameter, which I have no control over.